# Ordered combinations without repetition in php?

Tags: php, combinations

i have the following array:

Array("one", "two", "three", "four");

and i need a function that outputs all the ordered combinations of the array elements without repetition. The output should be

```
one
one two
one two three
one two three four
two
two three
two three four
three
three four
four
```

The output should not include:

```
one one
one two four
two one three
four two three
```

And so on ...

Does anybody of you have already implemented this kind of alghoritm?

Comment: Have you tried something? This seems pretty straightforward.

Comment: i have searched for various solutions on the web but all i found are permutations with/without repetitions that doesn't suits my need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would simply be two nested loops:

[Online demo](http://3v4l.org/S6U0R)

```
function permutation(array $arr)
{
    while($ele=array_shift($arr))
    {
        $x=$ele;
        echo $x."\n";
        foreach($arr as $rest)
        {
            $x.=" $rest";
            echo $x."\n";
        }
    }
}
permutation(array("one","two","three","four"));
```

Comment: You're missing combinations, for example there's no combination of one and four.

Comment: @TinusGuichelaar Have you seen the online demo? It outputs exactly like OP's desire. The 4th line has one and four.